# Pandas read_pickle from s3 bucket

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a *Jupyter* notebook from *AWS EMR*.

I am able to do this:
`pd.read_csv("s3:\\mypath\\xyz.csv')`.

However, if I try to open a pickle file like this, `pd.read_pickle("s3:\\mypath\\xyz.pkl")`

I am getting this error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://pvarma1/users/users/candidate_users.pkl'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py", line 179, in read_pickle
    return try_read(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py", line 177, in try_read
    lambda f: pc.load(f, encoding=encoding, compat=True))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py", line 146, in read_wrapper
    is_text=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 421, in _get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or d
```

However, I can see both `xyz.csv` and `xyz.pkl` in the same path! Can anyone help?

Comment: Both files have same permissions?

Comment: Yes, both have same permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandas `read_pickle` supports only local paths, unlike `read_csv`. So you should be copying the pickle file to your machine before reading it in pandas.

Comment: Thanks Aswin! I guessed it, but couldn't find any documentation. Could you please point me to the documentation.

Comment: @pvarma If you see the read_csv documentation, it specifically says it accepts https, s3, e.t.c. But pickle documentation does not. And it does not support because pickle files are `not secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data` as per their documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3

class DataPickleDownloadException(Exception):
    pass

BUCKET_NAME = "my-bucket"
LOCAL_FOLDER = "/tmp/"


s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

def _download_pickle_data_from_s3(file_name: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Download pickle DataFrame from S3 bucket and return it
    """
    try:
        s3_client.download_file(BUCKET_NAME, file_name, LOCAL_FOLDER + file_name)
        with open(LOCAL_FOLDER + file_name, "rb") as input_file:
            data = pd.read_pickle(input_file)
    except Exception as e:
        print(file_name, "- failed to download from S3, so terminate.")
        print(e)
        raise e
    if not isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
        exception_message = (
            file_name + "- is not a pandas DataFrame, strange, raise Exception"
        )
        print(exception_message)
        raise DataPickleDownloadException(exception_message)
    # here you can check the columns of the DataFrame
    print(file_name, "- downloaded OK, passed checks")
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `read_pickle` does not support this, you can use `smart_open`:

```
from smart_open import open 
s3_file_name = "s3://bucket/key"
with open(s3_file_name, 'rb') as f:
   df = pd.read_pickle(f)
```